# Insert row if it doesn't exist in more then one table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have two tables:
One is for active users and the other one is for inactive users. Both have full name of the user and his email address.
I want to be able to insert a new user only if he doesn't exist (his email address for instance) in both tables.
If he exists in the inactive table I will reactivate him by just moving the user from the inactive table to the active table.

Is there a way doing that by just trying to insert with some kind of query and catching exception if he exists, and not by checking if the user exists before inserting?

Comment: Put a trigger on table trying to insert and check for existence on other table.  If exists do your move.

Comment: Don't you think it would be smarted to make one user table and use a 0 or 1 to appoint activity? is_active = 0/1... It would make for an easier check too i guess

Comment: Might not be an option for you, but I would have them all in the same table with a boolean-field to specify if they are active or not

Comment: CaptainCarl and OlleR - I already thought about this solution, but my tables are very very big, and if I will have only one table to handle both the active and inactive users it won't be as efficient as using two separate tables.

Comment: xQbert - but if the user doesn't exist in the inactive users table he will be inserted into both tables and then I'll need to delete him from the inactive users table. which will cause unwanted, needless actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because your data is huge doesn't mean you should split it in two, this will cause you a lot of headache. You will have trouble not only in CRUD operations but also in linking your table to other tables. You should definitely have one table and a boolean field to indicate if the user is active or inactive.

To deal with the large data and speed of the queries in turn, you can take other actions like [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-list.html).

P.s: What you are trying to do is somehow reinventing partitions.

Comment: Thanks @jurgenreza. Do you have some kind of examples of partitioning and indexing?

Comment: @Yaniv depends on the DBMS you are you using. Mysql? SQL Server?

Comment: when querying partitioned table, will I still need to use WHERE active = 1 ? Or there is another way?

Comment: @Yaniv Yes. But that is a good thing. The partitioning is transparent to any queries you write. There is no need to specify what partition to query. The database just uses the partitions underneath to optimize accordingly and ideally reducing the amount of data or indexes it needs to search through based on you where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing conditional logic by catching exceptions is an inefficient design. You'd be much better off by simply checking first to see if the email address exists in either table:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM InactiveUsers WHERE Email = @new_email)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ActiveUsers ...
    DELETE FROM InactiveUsers ...
    END
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ActiveUsers WHERE Email = @new_email)
    INSERT INTO ActiveUsers...
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I know if the user is eventually been inserted or not?

Comment: I've updated the pseudocode; but you don't need to check if the user has been inserted - the insert will work, otherwise it will have thrown an error.